# pop-up positioning issue while hitting on share button

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

i have created a iPad application and i have used a share image button on navigation bar, and used action sheet on it i want this action sheet to be pop-up below the navigation bar's "share image" icon, cam someone help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy.  Just like this:

```
[self.popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:BUTTON_ITEM
                               permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny 
                                               animated:YES];
```